# How to stretch a data frame by decollapsing a column containing vectors in r?

Tags: r, reshape2

I have a data frame with a column containing vectors as values. Now I need to stretch this data frame by decollapsing the vectors.

Take a look at this example:

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), id2 = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), value = c("1", "2", "3", "c(1,3,4)", 
"1:5", "1", "2", "3", "1:4", "2:4")), .Names = c("id", "id2", 
"value"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
df
   id id2    value
1   1   1        1
2   1   2        2
3   1   3        3
4   1   4 c(1,3,4)
5   1   5      1:5
6   2   1        1
7   2   2        2
8   2   3        3
9   2   4      1:4
10  2   5      2:4

this has to be changed into:

df2 <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), id2 = c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 5L), value = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L)), .Names = c("id", 
"id2", "value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -21L
))

df2
   id id2 value
1   1   1     1
2   1   2     2
3   1   3     3
4   1   4     1
5   1   4     3
6   1   4     4
7   1   5     1
8   1   5     2
9   1   5     3
10  1   5     4
11  1   5     5
12  2   1     1
13  2   2     2
14  2   3     3
15  2   4     1
16  2   4     2
17  2   4     3
18  2   4     4
19  2   5     2
20  2   5     3
21  2   5     4
```

So it's a different kind of turning a wide format into a long one than we are used to with functions from e.g. the reshape2 package. Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

*Edit

I forgot to mention that some of the values are in fact character values like this:

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), id2 = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), value = c("1", "2", "Hi", "c(1,3,4)", 
"1:5", "1", "2", "hello", "1:4", "2:4")), .Names = c("id", "id2", 
"value"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
df
   id id2    value
1   1   1        1
2   1   2        2
3   1   3       Hi
4   1   4 c(1,3,4)
5   1   5      1:5
6   2   1        1
7   2   2        2
8   2   3    hello
9   2   4      1:4
10  2   5      2:4
```

Comment: So what is your desired output per your edit?

Comment: How did you wind up with such a terrible data format? Was this file created with R in the first place?

Comment: Yeah, the data now looks like some type of an Aprils fools joke.

Comment: I must admit, it's terrible :-). It was a json file that I converted to a data frame

Comment: I think I can make a function with your solutions. I suddenly realised that specific kinds of id2's always contain words. I defilter them first.

Comment: `jsonlite::fromJSON` returns some crazy dataframes like this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do

```
df$value <- lapply(df$value, function(x) {
  res <- try(eval(parse(text=x)), silent=T)
  if (!inherits(res, "try-error")) as.character(res) else x
})
# install.packages("tidyr") # uncomment and run if needed
tidyr::unnest(df)
# Source: local data frame [21 x 3]
# 
#       id   id2 value
#    (dbl) (dbl) (chr)
# 1      1     1     1
# 2      1     2     2
# 3      1     3    Hi
# 4      1     4     1
# 5      1     4     3
# 6      1     4     4
# 7      1     5     1
# 8      1     5     2
# 9      1     5     3
# 10     1     5     4
# ..   ...   ...   ...
```

However, this may not be the most elegant option.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer! I forgot to mention that some of the values are character values, like names. your solutions gives an error:  Error in parse(text = x) : <text>:1:6: unexpected symbol. Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 6):

Similarly a one liner using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, as.integer(eval.parent(parse(text = value))), by = .(id, id2)]
#     id id2 V1
#  1:  1   1  1
#  2:  1   2  2
#  3:  1   3  3
#  4:  1   4  1
#  5:  1   4  3
#  6:  1   4  4
#  7:  1   5  1
#  8:  1   5  2
#  9:  1   5  3
# 10:  1   5  4
# 11:  1   5  5
# 12:  2   1  1
# 13:  2   2  2
# 14:  2   3  3
# 15:  2   4  1
# 16:  2   4  2
# 17:  2   4  3
# 18:  2   4  4
# 19:  2   5  2
# 20:  2   5  3
# 21:  2   5  4
```